# Issue with Appium Inspector: Incorrect Element Position displayed

Tags: automated-tests, appium, appium-java

I'm facing a peculiar issue with Appium Inspector. When I move the cursor to the left side of my emulator screen to get xpath of any element, the selected area in the Inspector shifts to a different element rather than the intended area. Additionally, slight movements in the cursor (up, down, left, right) result in the selection of unwanted elements.
I am attaching [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPr4l.png) for reference. The wrong highlighted area is in yellow color.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Resolved the issue by downgrading the Appium Inspector version from 2023.11.1 to 2023.8.2. The problem with incorrect element selection was attributed to the Appium Inspector version, and the downgrade successfully addressed the issue.